# How to Build nginx 1.4.0 and ngx_pagespeed in Ubuntu/Debian?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, mod-pagespeed, page-speed

**How to Build nginx 1.4.0 and ngx_pagespeed in Ubuntu**

Create a directory to download necessary packages (optional) :

```
mkdir pagespeed && cd pagespeed
```

Make sure that you have latest version of nginx, I recommend using nginx repo.

To add nginx repo :

```
wget http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key
sudo apt-key add nginx_signing.key
```

Add this lines to /etc/apt/sources.list file:

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ codename nginx (for 12.04 codename is squeeze)
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/debian/ codename nginx
```

Download nginx sources and build packages :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
sudo apt-get source nginx
```

Build nginx deps :

```
sudo apt-get build-dep nginx
```

Make sure you have this ngx_pagespeed requirements :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
```

Clone ngx_pagespeed git repo :

```
git clone https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed.git
```

Edit build rules for nginx 1.4 package :

```
vim nginx-1.4.0/debian/rules
```

and add :

```
--add-module=../ngx_pagespeed \
```

it will look like this :

```
...
--with-file-aio \
--add-module=../ngx_pagespeed \
$(WITH_SPDY) \
--with-ipv6
...
```

Build nginx 1.4.0 debian package with pagespeed module :

```
cd nginx-1.4.0/ && dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

Install new nginx deb package:

```
cd .. && dpkg --install nginx_1.4.0-1~squeeze_amd64.deb
```

> `If you have nginx installed you will need to remove it and then reinstall the new package ( do not use --purge options otherwise you will delete all your config files)`

Add this lines to /etc/nginx.conf to test if pagespeed works :

```
...
http {
    pagespeed on;
    pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
...
```

Create pagespeed cache directory and change permissions :

```
mkdir /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache
```

Reload nginx :

```
nginx -s reload
```

Test if pagespeed is working :

```
curl -I -p http://localhost:8080/index.php|grep X-Page-Speed
```

> make sure to use the correct url

you should see :

```
X-Page-Speed: 1.5.27.1-2845
```

If you see that header you are done enjoy!!!

Now you need to RT?M!!

For More detailed information please read :

https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed

http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable

Any feedback on this instructions is welcome

> This process could be used to build basically any module for nginx that is not on the nginx-full or default dedian package

Comment: Hi, PePe. Rather than StackExchange acting like a forum where you might pool your knowledge, it's instead a question and answer site. You've posted an answer as a question, so would you mind editing the main body of the actual question into a question, and then post the rest of your question as an answer when you can. For more information on how Stackexchange sites work, see the FAQ and About tabs at the top of the page.

Comment: Sorry I will do it next time, right now I can't since it is already closed

Comment: http://blog.amengual.cl/index.php/archives/1 for updated instrucctions